# Excluding Data Fixtures for being autloaded by composer in a Symfony 3.4 application

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony-3.4, autoloader

I am using `doctrine/data-fixtures` in dev environments and require it as follows:

composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "": "src/",
        "SymfonyStandard": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
},
"require-dev": {
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.8",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "dev-rfc1872 as v1.2.1",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.0"
},
```

In my Symfony 3.4 application my data fixtures live in `/src/AppBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/*.php`.

When I run composer, which in turn runs a Symfony cache:clear I get the following error:

> [RuntimeException]
>   An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'"
>   command:
>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       In DefinitionErrorExceptionPass.php line 37:
>
> ```
> While discovering services from namespace "AppBundle\", an error was thrown    
>  when processing the class "AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadCourseData": "Cl    
> ass Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture not found".
> ```

I would like to exclude the DataFixtures namespace from being autoloaded but I cannot find a way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't want to exclude data fixtures from being autoloaded, because they are valid PHP classes.

This error comes from Symfony's autowiring feature. So I assume you're indeed using autowiring.
You should data fixtures from autowiring discovery, which can be done in `services.yml` with `exclude` option.

Assuming you have something like (which should be there by default):

```
AppBundle\:
    resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
    exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository}'
```

All you need to do is to add `DataFixtures` namespace to `exclude`:

```
AppBundle\:
    resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
    exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,DataFixtures}'
```

You can read more about it in [here](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html) nad [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container)